# WordPress Custom Field Suite & Gallery Add-on

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using WordPress Custom Field Suite plugin which is an excellent plugin. I'm trying to include the Gallery add-on in the loop. Here are the documentation links for both:

Custom Field Suite (get API)
https://mgibbs189.github.io/custom-field-suite/api/get.html

CFS Gallery Add-on
https://github.com/zastrich/cfs-gallery

Here's my code so far without the Gallery add-on code:

```
<?php    
$fields = CFS()->get( 'add_edit_item' );    
    foreach ( $fields as $row ) {       
    echo '<img src="' . $row['list_image'] . '">';    
    echo '<h2>' . $row['item_name'] . '</h2>';   
    echo '<p>' . $row['price'] . '</p>';} 
?>
```

Here's the code from the Gallery add-on documentation but I'm not a PHP programmer and I've no idea how to code it in the loop above:

```
$Images = CFS()->get("gallery"); /* Return array of Image IDs */

if(is_array($Images) && sizeof($Images) > 0)
foreach($Images as $ImageID){
    $Image = get_post($ImageID); /* Get properties of image post by ID */
    ?>
    <a href="<?=@array_shift(wp_get_attachment_image_src($ImageID, "full"))?>">
        <img src="<?=@array_shift(wp_get_attachment_image_src($ImageID, "large"))?>" alt="<?=$Image->post_content?>">
    </a>
    <?php 
}
```

I can get it to work independently outside of the loop. I'd be grateful for any help.